# What is causing this strange Mathematica result?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I've run into what seems like a bug in Mathematica 8. I can't find anything related to it online, but I admit I'm not exactly sure what to search for.

If I run this statement:

```
0.05 + .10 /. {0.15 -> "pass"}
1.04 + .10 /. {1.14 -> "pass"}
1.05 + .10 /. {1.15 -> "pass"}
1.15 /. {1.15 -> "pass"}
```

I get this output:

```
pass

pass

1.15

pass
```

Am I just overlooking something?

**Edit:** After reading the helpful discussion below, I changed my dispatch table to use a Which statement instead:

```
f[x_] := Which[x == 1.05, -1.709847, x == 1.10, -1.373823, 
  x == 1.15, -1.119214, x == 1.20, -0.9160143, x == 1.25, -0.7470223, x == 1.30, -0.6015966]
```

This seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Welcome to the world of machine precision. If you examine 1.05 +.10 and 1.15 more closely, you'll see that they're not quite the same:

```
1.05 + .10 // FullForm

==> 1.1500000000000001`

1.15 // FullForm

==> 1.15`
```

Comment: I thought I was ruling out a precision issue by showing those other cases. Why would only one particular case fail?

Comment: +1. Just to complement the answer: instead of the original rules, one may define some kind of tolerance, and encode that into a rule, like say `With[{eps = 0.001}, rule[value_] := x_ /; Abs[x - value] < eps -> "pass"]`. In this way, your rules will work, say `1.05+.10/.{rule[1.15]}`.

Comment: @sapient network The point is, you can not rely on this, even if it occasionally works. Other rules worked by a coincidence. Doing it this way, you introduce what in other languages would be called "undefined behavior" - that is, the system gives you no guarantee what will happen.

Comment: Funny. It is a long time since I've used Mathematica (>10years ago) and I thought this was always about not falling back to the limitations of the machine floating point libraries.

Comment: @Heiko Mathematica can work in arbitrary precision if you like, but the default in many cases is machine precision, because this is so much faster.

Comment: @Heiko I think that the degree to which a language allows one to make mistakes of various kinds is a measure (one of the) of the language's hackability. Mathematica is a very hackable language, and I like it for that. Mixing syntactic comparisons (including rule application) and numerics is one such mistake, and a well-known one.  It is also easily avoided.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to incurring small errors when using `MachinePrecision`, the same floating-point calculation can produce slightly different results at different times of the day. This is not a bug, but rather a [by-product](http://thenumericalalgorithmsgroup.blogspot.com/2011/02/wandering-precision.html) of how modern hardware floating-point architectures work

This means you should not use operations like `ReplaceAll` that depend on knowing exact value of `MachinePrecision` numbers. Using `==` (and `===`) might be OK because they ignore last 7 (respectively 1) binary digit of `MachinePrecision` numbers.

Using Mathematica arithmetic should give exact results regardless of time of day, you could use it for your example as follows (10 significant digits)

```
0.05`10 + .10`10 /. {0.15`10 -> "pass"}
1.04`10 + .10`10 /. {1.14`10 -> "pass"}
1.05`10 + .10`10 /. {1.15`10 -> "pass"}
1.15`10 /. {1.15`10 -> "pass"}
```

**Update**: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.22.6768) gives some more caveats about floating point arithmetic. For instance, page 80 gives examples of how different implementations of IEEE 754 give slightly different results, even despite being standard compliant

Comment: From the end of the note at your URL: "the [...] extended precision 80-bit register arithmetic [...] had its own "wobbling precision" problems for numerical code". This issue has not gone away. Different compilers and optimization levels might cause, or not, a storage from 80 bit register to 64 bit memory. This can lead to such oddities. We've looked into several in the past few years.

Comment: @Daniel You mean that the old problem with [`non-deterministic numerical inaccuracies`](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/browse_thread/thread/ef015dccb5bef4a5/699400c89e64d684?#699400c89e64d684) is not completely solved?

Comment: @Alexey It is not in any way "solvable", at least not by means accessible to us (which in some sense defines it as "not a problem"). Depends too much on alignment-handling vagaries of MKL libraries, ordering of operations in BLAS, and usage, or not, of extended precision registers. See also IEEE 754: a careful reading may shed light on how different results for the same computation can arise in compliant hardware/software, even on the same machine.

Comment: @Daniel Are there in *Mathematica* tools which allow to be sure that numerical results will be deterministic?

Comment: @Alexey: you could turn on precision tracking (using `SetPrecision` or 0.1'10 syntax) and zero-out digits in result that are outside of precision

Comment: @Alexey I cannot imagine how that might be done with machine arithmetic; it is impossible with current hardware and software(*). For significance arithmetic the approach mentioned by Yaroslav should suffice. (*) One might choose to regard this as a deplorable state of affairs, but it is a fact nonetheless.

Comment: @Yaroslav @Daniel How much should I increase precision to be sure? 1.04`4 + .10`4 /. {1.14`4 -> "pass"} does not work. And what about the case if I only want results to be deterministic but not to control precision (that is time-consuming)?

Comment: @Daniel Can I solve the problem by using a processor with different architecture? For example, AMD processor instead of Intel?

Comment: 1.04`4 + .10`4 /. {1.14`4 -> "pass"} works for me. You should specify precision that's high enough to give required precision in your answer. IE, if you want at least 10 correct digits, you could start with precision 10, and increase if that's not sufficient. `N[a,10]` does this automatically. If your computation is numerically unstable like logistic map, getting even a single guaranteed digit may be impossible. The article described non-determinism to be an issue with SSE, which are used in Intel since '99 and in AMD since '01, so using chips produced more than 10 years ago may work

Comment: @Yaroslav The article says: "We could choose not to use SSE instructions at all. But, apart from efficiency reasons, the "legacy" extended precision 80-bit register arithmetic which started in the 1980s with the 8087 numeric co-processor had its own "wobbling precision" problems for numerical code." It deprives me of certainty…

Comment: @Yaroslav Probably 1.04`4 + .10`4 /. {1.14`4 -> "pass"} works for you because you use Mathematica 8 (I'm using v.7.01). Or may be because you have 64-bit processor - but it seems that [`there is no significant difference between 32-bit and 64-bit versions of Mathematica`](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/msg/c146ae59ae46c91a).

Comment: interesting, what's the difference between FullForm of RHS and LHS?

Comment: @Yaroslav What do you mean? Give an example, please.

Comment: I mean what exactly is the difference between .04`4 + .10`4  and 1.14`4 ?

Comment: @Yaroslav Good question! I want to know it too! I think we should open a separate question on it.

Comment: No, I mean, can you post FullForm of .04`4 + .10`4 and FullForm of 1.14`4. On my system, there's no difference and it works as expected

Comment: @Yaroslav **1.14`4 // FullForm** and **(1.04`4 + .10`4) // FullForm** and **(1.04`4 + .10`4 /. {1.14`4 -> "pass"}) // FullForm** all gives exactly the same: **1.14`4.**

Comment: @Yaroslav Moreover `BoxData[...]` in the all these Output Cells (shown by pressing Shift+Ctrl+E) is identical: **BoxData[
  TagBox[
    StyleBox["1.14`4.",
      ShowSpecialCharacters -> False,
      ShowStringCharacters -> True,
      NumberMarks -> True],
    FullForm]]**

Comment: @Alexey Depriving you of certainty is probably the lesser of troubles that might arise with extended prec registers. A bigger issue, to me, is that exponent sizes are larger than for double prec. So an overflow might happen, or not, depending on optimization levels that influence whether an intermediate value in a string of computations is kept in a register or stored. Compared to this, relatively modest differences in well conditioned computations strike me as of less significance, if you will pardon the expression.

Comment: @Yaroslav It is interesting that in **Precision[1.04`4 + .10`4] // FullForm** gives **3.9999999999999996`** but **1.04`4 + .10`4 // FullForm** gives **1.14`4.**. In *Mathematica* 5.2 **1.04`4 + .10`4 // FullForm** gives **1.14`3.9999999999999996**. There is something strange with `FullForm` in *Mathematica* 7.01... :(

Comment: @Alexey I can explain that FullForm, I think. Significance arithmetic (aka "precision tracking") does suffer from precision loss in the course of arithmetic operations. The precision is stored, to close approximation, as a machine double. This fact implies it will have a (small) granularity. And error tracking causes this to be rounded outward, that is, conservatively. In your example above the operation of addition caused a loss of what appears to be an ULP's worth of precision. For purposes of equality testing this should be okay because Equal will coerce one argument to the lower precision.

Comment: @Daniel I do not understand your point completely. Do you mean that when adding two numbers with the same Precision there are some arithmetic operations with their Precisions leading in precision loss for the final value of Precision? But why this happens when the Precisions are identical and have exact binary representation? And what operations are there which gives such effect? The second question is why in *Mathematica* 7.01 `FullForm` shows rounded Precision? This causes a deal of confusion.

Comment: @Alexey Not sure myself about the entire set of pathologies. What goes amiss in your example was something I did not quite catch. InputForm[Precision;1/14`4]] will also show that slightly smaller (by an ULP) precision of 4 minus machine epsilon. I rather suspect the reason is that 1.14 is not exactly representable in binary. Your point about adding positive values of identical precision looks correct to me. That is to say, that alone should not alter precision.

Comment: @Daniel It is sad that we face even at the so fundamental level irremovable mysticism along with the non-determinism. I hoped that at least at the level of the foundation of the system such things were still unambiguous. :(

Answer (score 4):

Your replacements only work on exact matches, whereas your While statement uses `Equal`.  You can make the rule based approach work by using `Equal` as well.

```
0.05 + .10 /. {x_ /; x == 0.15 -> "pass"}
1.04 + .10 /. {x_ /; x == 1.14 -> "pass"}
1.05 + .10 /. {x_ /; x == 1.15 -> "pass"}
1.15 /. {x_ /; x == 1.15 -> "pass"}
```