# Using Position correctly

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

In the [mma help docs for `Position`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Position.html), the following is listed under "Possible Issues"

```
In[1]:= Position[Range[-1, 1, 0.05], 0.1]
Out[1]= {}
```

There is no explanation given though. Why does this happen? So if I really need to find the position of `0.1` in `Range[-1,1,0.05]`, how do I do it?

Comment: Ignore the close vote... I was just amused to see the vote to close option, even though I don't have enough rep and cast one. I can see that it works only on my posts and not the entire site :/

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5185281/what-is-causing-this-strange-mathematica-result

Comment: o'b You've had an intense day today. Exhausting your votes and voting to close your own post ... pheeeew :)

Comment: Or maybe just use `Position[N@Range[-1, 1, 1/20], 0.1]`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is a numeric precision issue: 0.1 in the `Range` is not internally the same as 0.1 typed in.  The normal way to resolve this is to compare with `Equal` rather than the implicit `SameQ`.

```
Position[Range[-1, 1, 0.05], x_ /; x == 0.1]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I still am confused a bit. If I do `FullForm@Range[-1, 1, 0.05]`, the corresponding value for `0.1` is `0.10000000000000009`. Now if I do `0.10000000000000009==1`, I get `False`. Why does it return `True` in your code (which is presumably how it finds the position)?

Comment: You just wrote: `0.10000000000000009==1` but I think you mean `0.10000000000000009 == 0.1`; does that still return `False`?

Comment: @d'o-o'b, no you're not, we all do that.  By the way, thanks for the accept, but I notice you did not vote for my answer.  Are you aware that you can both vote for and accept an answer?  I am not too proud to beg for my votes. ;-)

Comment: I know I can, but I used up all my 30 today and earned a cool suffrage badge :) I'll vote you up in ~30 mins when it's a new day in London town.