# Mathematica Position of Elements of a List that fulfill an inequality

Tags: position, wolfram-mathematica

The task I have is pretty simple but I can not solve it in mathematica.
Given a list

`myList = {1, 3, 4}`

I would like to get the position of entries smaller than a number - say 2 in the example above.
Attempts such as

`Position[myList, #[[1]] < 2 &]`

`Position[myList, # < 2 &]`

which would be similar to the function `SELECT` don't work. How can I use `Position` or some other function. Thanks!

Comment: This question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5750623/using-position-correctly answers mine.

Comment: But why is the usage of POSITION that different to SELECT?

Comment: Select takes as its argument a function, whereas Position takes as its argument a pattern. Patterns and functions, two different paradigms.

Comment: I still have problems with Position[myList, x_ /; x < 0.0001`]. It just does not interpret the decimal corretly. Do you know how to solve this @Calle?

Comment: You shouldn't have a problem with that. Post the full code/the list.

Comment: I have edited the question. I hope that helps.

Comment: Ok, there is an error in my data ... sorry, please don't spend more time on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Reason**: The reason is that Position takes a *pattern* not a *function*.
(i.e. Position[-list-,-pattern-])

**Solution**:

```
Position[myList, x_ /; x < 2]  
{{1}}
```

Similarly:

```
myList2 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, "notNumber"}
Position[myList2, x_ /; x < 3] 
{{1}, {2}, {6}}
```

(i.e. Position[ myList, element_x where element_x < 2])

/; <-- denotes a condition (Super useful when defining functions over specific inputs too!)

x_ <-- is a named "pattern object"

x <-- is a reference to the pattern object

**Deeper Reason**:
I don't know exactly what the Mathematica internals look like, but I imagine it runs something like this: if you use a functional description instead of a pattern description (i.e. #...& instead of x_/;...) the function looks for patterns that contain "#...&" which doesn't make sense (since it's comparing objects not feeding them to your defined function).  On the other hand when you use a pattern description it compares them, then checks the conditional for truth (the conditional limiting matches, the widely defined x_ matching everything) and you get meaningful matching.  Flip all that for functions defined to work with other functions.

I love Mathematica, but it's not good at making it's pattern based functions and function based functions obviously separate from eachother (aside from looking at documentation).

Hope that helps.